# Why am I able to flag my own questions?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

I just noticed that I (as everyone else) can flag my own questions.
There are fewer options (no *"spam"*, *"rude or abusive"* nor *"very low quality"*) to choose, but it's still possible to flag your own question as *"should be closed"* or *"duplicate"*.

I don't understand, if that is the case, shouldn't I just delete the question?
What's the purpose of having this options?

Comment: ... or as "*needs moderator attention*".

Comment: @amWhy I figured that's a special case and it's there because "you never know". But, yeah, that too!

Comment: Relevant: [Why can I flag my own question/answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170427) and [Flag and close my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176386).

Comment: I always like to express a certain sense of humility when I flag myself. *flies away with a spam flag

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What if someone makes a few unsavory comments, or edits, or enters an edit war on your question? Shouldn't you be able and notify the moderators? What if you decide that it might be better to migrate the question to a different site on the SE network, but there are useful comments or answers that are worth preserving?

Yes, you could potentially raise a flag on a different post and link back, but this is vastly easier when you flag the actual post (the same way that when you arm hurts, it's easier to know that the pain actually comes from your arm, rather than your chest)

Comment: But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referred_pain

Comment: Yes, that was my point.

Comment: @Asaf can you lift the ban imposed on my account , I am unable to ask questions, I have many positive contributions to this site ,(you can check it). Please do the needful. It is a humble request

Comment: @AkashRoy: I did not put any ban on your account. This is an automatic software ban which the moderators are unable to control. Why would you think it's me, of all people?

Comment: I did not accuse you of banning my account @Asaf I just wanted to know when would the ban be lifted. I don't think that asking a moderator regarding some issue is a crime

Answer (score 16):

If your question has an upvoted answer it cannot be self-deleted anymore. That's one reason why it can make sense to self-close rather than to self-delete.

Another reason is that some duplicates are worth preserving *as duplicates* and should not be deleted. For example if you used different terminology to describe the same thing, later searches might find your version rather then the other.

Comment: Also, one can flag one's own post (question or answer) for moderator attention when one is concerned it has been inappropriately targeted (usually, in such a case, there are other posts or yours which have been similarly downvoted that one should mention in such a flag).

Comment: Any asker can also flag their own question to ask that a moderator designate the question as a *Community Wiki* question, particularly when the question is a soft question, or polling for ideas, suggestions, etc, which can't be adequately fully answered in one answer.